# vscode: Extension to do simple global search

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to create an extension that does a very simple task:

I invoke a command from the command pallet with:

```
> commandName: Query
```

And it should start a global search, in regex mode with:

```
SomeToken AnotherToken (some|regex*|prefix?|foo) Query
```

**Where the point is that I don't want to type the `SomeToken AnotherToken (some|regex*|prefix?|foo)` prefix all the time.**

This sounds like a very simple process and I expected it to be possible in vscode, but I haven't found anything yet about it in the VSCode API and relevant tutorials.

Comment: why does the `Search Bar` not work for you (Ctrl+Shift+F), Also look for the `Open New Search Editor` button at the top of this bar

Comment: I am not keen on manually opening the search bar (even through keyboard, which I already do) because typing in the regex prefix would be a hassle and I would like to optimize my workflow :). I will make that clear in the question.

Comment: the search and replace fields have a history, use the Up and Down Arrow Keys. You can have the extension fill the clipboard with the string you want, or you can try to set up a keybinding that uses the `type` command to type the string needed, or let the extension use the `type` command when the focus is on the search find field (keybinding `where` clause)

Comment: The history is cool, but not really optimal for my use case. Clipboard is one step better, but still adds one redundant step that you need to manually invoke the search as well. The type command seems the most promising, but I wonder, can you also force the focus (programmatically) on the search find field? then I can have the whole process end-to-end with one command invocation.

Comment: What do each f these represent: `SomeToken AnotherToken (some|regex*|prefix?|foo)`?  It is hard to help if we don't know exactly what you want to input to where.  Is `SomeToken` the search term, `AnotherToken` the replace term and `(some|regex*|prefix?|foo)` is what exactly?

Comment: There are just some tokens that should exist in the search query. I can explain the exact use case. The following regex is super useful for Rust when you want to look for the definition of a trait/struct and all implementors: `(enum|struct|fn|trait|impl(<.*>)?|type) $1` and what I want is a _single command_ that would fill this into the global search field, and replace the `$1` with whatever the command was invoked with.

Comment: I have a similar use. I have a task defined that calls a python script that does the search based on arguments and outputs lines that are handled by a problem matcher and through the PROBLEM paneI can jump to the file. You can use the selected text in the task definition

Comment: @rioV8 possible to share an example/source code?

Comment: you better use `impl(<.*?>)?`

Comment: What would `<.*?>` mean? `*` already means optional, what does `?` add to this?

Comment: `.*?` is the non-greedy version of `.*`: take as few characters as possible to satisfy the expression, if there is a second `>` on the line `.*` will capture up to that character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have released an extension which does allow you to create and save pre-defined find/replaces or search/replaces: [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform) and call them via commands in the Command Palette or through keybindings.  Sample settings:

```
    "findInCurrentFile": {
        "upcaseSwap2": {
            "title": "swap iif <==> hello",
            "find": "(iif) (hello)",
            "replace": "_\\u$2_ _\\U$1_",  // double-escaped case modifiers
            "restrictFind": "selections"
        },
        "upcaseSelectedKeywords": {
            "title": "Uppercase selected Keywords",
            "find": "(epsilon|alpha|beta)",
            "replace": "\\U$1",
            // "restrictFind": "selections"
        }
    },

    "runInSearchPanel": {
        "removeDigits": {
            "title": "Remove digits from Arturo",
            "find": "^(\\s*Arturo)\\d+",
            "replace": "$1",
            "isRegex": true,
            "triggerSearch": true,
            // "filesToInclude": "${file}"
            "filesToInclude": "${file}",
        }
    },
```

---

- I don't think there is any way to invoke a command from the Command Palette with an argument as you seem to indicate you wish to do.  You could open an InputBox and ask for that value (that is quite easy to do) or use the currently selected text. Below I showed both ways.

---

First with the currently selected text you can just try a simple keybinding and see if that is sufficient:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+g",                    // whatever keybinding you wish
  "command": "search.action.openNewEditor",
  "args": {

    "query": "(enum|struct|fn|trait|impl(<.*>)?|type) ${selectedText}",

    "isRegexp": true,

    // "includes": "${relativeFile}",  // works

    "showIncludesExcludes": true,
    "triggerSearch": true,
    "contextLines": 2,
    "focusResults": true,
  },
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

It opens up a search editor rather than using your Search view/panel.  If you want it in the Search view/panel that isn't as easy.  Unfortunately the `workbench.action.findInFiles` args do not support `${selectedText}`.  Nevertheless you can do this keybinding and simply type the rest of your query at the end.

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+f",
    "command": "workbench.action.findInFiles",
    "args": {

      "query": "(enum|struct|fn|trait|impl(<.*>)?|type) ",
      "isRegex": true,
      // "replace": "$1",
      "triggerSearch": true,                          // seems to be the default
      // "filesToInclude": "${relativeFileDirname}",  // no variables in findInFiles
      "preserveCase": true,
      "useExcludeSettingsAndIgnoreFiles": false,
      "isCaseSensitive": true,
      // "matchWholeWord": true,
      // "filesToExclude": ""
    }
  },
```

---

Here is the guts of extension code using the selected text that would be in your `vscode.commands.registerCommand` call:

```js
let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('myExtensionName.myCommandName', function () {

  // get selected text or open an InputBox here

  const selection = vscode.window.activeTextEditor.selection;
  const selectedText = vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.getText(selection);

  const searchOptions = {
    query: "(enum|struct|fn|trait|impl(<.*>)?|type) " + selectedText,
    triggerSearch: true,
    isRegex: true
  };

  vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.findInFiles', searchOptions);
});

context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
```

---

And this opens an InputBox to get the query term from the user:

```js
let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('myExtensionName.myCommandName', function () {

  vscode.window.showInputBox({ prompt: "Enter a search query" }).then(query => {

    const searchOptions = {
      query: "(enum|struct|fn|trait|impl(<.*>)?|type) " + query,
      triggerSearch: true,
      isRegex: true
    };

    vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.findInFiles', searchOptions);
  })
});

context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
```

Obviously you'll have to add some error checking.

Comment: Sorry for my delay @Mark, I was busy for a few days and bookmarked this to check out later. Your answer was superb, and now I have a few very good options to tune for my need. Thanks! I will write further feedback once I try all methods.